# Do we need to know first time derivatives of Klein-Gordon fields to make future predictions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation, canonical-conjugation

In the quantisation of the Klein Gordon field, because it has a second derivative, we need to know the values of the field and also the first derivative in order to predict future values of the field. $\phi(x),\pi(x)=\dot{\phi}(x)$. This is standard in differential equations.

But for the Feynman path integral approach, we just use the propagator $G$ to find future values of the field:

$$\phi(x,t')  = \int G_F(x-y,t-t')\phi(y,t) dy^3$$

with no mention of time derivates of the fields. With this transition function we can take any field from time $t$ to time $t'$ without seeming the need to know the time derivatives of the fields.

What happened to the ambiguity and the need for time derivatives? Are there some boundary conditions implied that removes the usual ambiguity for second order differential equations?

Edit: Is the above equation not valid for relativistic fields with second time derivatives?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "*But for the Feynman path integral approach, we just use $\phi(x,t')  = \int G_F(x-y,t-t')\phi(y,t) dy^3$ with no mention of time derivates of the fields.*" Use it for what? and use it how? And what is your definition of $G_F(x-y,t-t')$?

Comment: Yeah, I'm mixing notations. I've made it clearer. It is the Feynman propagator with the usual meaning.

Comment: 1) Your formula for $\phi(x,t')$ is not particular to the path-integral approach - it is also valid in the operator formalism. 2) Please, state explicitly what is the usual meaning for the Feynman propagator: how is it defined? be as specific as you can. The answer to your question lies precisely in the definition of the Feynman propagator.

Comment: Same as the definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator